# Triggering focus/blur/change from contenteditable via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to update after contenteditable changes and the code below works with events like "click", but not with "focus","change", etc.

Looking for a sensible way to run ajax updates as opposed to every click or something like that.

Is there a way to trigger these events from contenteditable?

```
$("#resume_holder").contents().on("click", function(e) {

 var txt = $(e.target).closest("section").html();
 var id = $(e.target).closest("section").attr('id');

 alert(txt+' '+id);
            $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '<?php echo site_url('resume/edit_resume_ajax'); ?>',
                    data: {
                        edit_id : id,                               
                        edit_value: txt
                    },
                    success : function(msg){
                    },
                    error: function(){

                    }
                }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue in part was that the iframe wasn't ready. The code below works:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#resume_holder").ready(function () {     

$('#resume_holder').contents().find('[contenteditable]').on("blur", function(e) {

     var txt = $(e.target).closest("section").html();
     var id = $(e.target).closest("section").attr('id');

                $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : '<?php echo site_url('resume/edit_resume_ajax'); ?>',
                        data: {
                            edit_id : id,                               
                            edit_value: txt
                        },
                        success : function(msg){
                        },
                        error: function(){

                        }
                    }); 
                }); 
            });

 });    
    </script>
```